# Security: testing sequence of encrypted numbers

Tags: security, encryption

Suppose that you have a sequence of ids that are encrypted by using algorithm X, in the form:

- 2b9ff1f86c9d5806030cd861db4304d8
- c9b8d142d9777c03c2b5824ce79378ff
- etc.

How can I test if this sequence is secure, i.e. that none can decrypt it?

Comment: Whether or not someone can decrypt your sequences depends one a number of things, including whether or not they have access to your encryption methods.

Comment: @SucSparc well, yes! If someone breaks the server, then he can read my PHP code! I cannot avoid this, it is a task for system administrators!

Comment: I would like to point out that these are most likely MD5 hashes, judging from the way they look. Of course there no way to be certain about this, so please ignore me if I am incorrect. Anyway, MD5 is not encrpytion, it's hashing. Hashes cannot be decrypted. It's an entirely different technology with a different purpose. More importantly, this shows you don't really know what you are doing and should listen to Olivier's answer.

Comment: @WouterH I didn't used MD5. However, notice that MD5 **is** a cryptographic hash function, not just a hash function: the aims are completely different. Maybe also you don't really know about this topic! :)

Comment: @mat_boy We seem to agree on the fact that MD5 is hashing. That's great. I'm glad that's the case.

Comment: @WouterH Ah Ah! Yes, we do agree on this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are required to meet some kind of contractual obligation, you'd be best off relying on a 3rd party expert analysis paper of the algorithm and implementation for your application in question.

Otherwise, there are [resources to help you evaluate how long it would take to crack various encryption methods](http://www.keylength.com/en/compare/) (in theory, on average).

Any encryption can be cracked given enough time and computing resources, so the goal is to increase the time it takes to crack it such that the data once cracked has a lower value than the time it takes to crack it, for as long as the data are valuable.

Comment: Note that key length is only applicable if the underlying encryption algorithm is secure. If it is flawed, all bets are off.

Comment: It's a good practice to assume that everything is flawed.  Even a mathematically perfect algorithm probably has implementation flaws that can be exploited.  Even a perfect implementation of a perfect algorithm might be subjected to hardware flaws.  Even perfect hardware running a perfect implementation of a perfect algorithm is subject to social engineering...

Comment: +1 to this warning ^^ And about "not-so-social engineering" -vs- cryptography, http://xkcd.com/538

Comment: Very useful. Thank you! I will change the encryption algorithm based on that resource!

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The only effective way to test something like this is to analyze the *design*, not just its output. (If the security of your system depends on its inner workings remaining secret, it is not secure; see [Kerckhoff's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle).)

Note that this testing must inherently be done by a knowledgeable human; it cannot be automated. Cryptographic analysis is a process which requires human ingenuity.

Comment: Safe is a relative term. Yes, they could be very safe, to a certain degree, but it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: @SunSparc Exists any real possibility to see my encrypted ids being decrypted?

Comment: If you are using an encryption algorithm which you designed yourself, your data is almost certainly **not** safe.

Comment: @duskwuff Are you kidding me? Do you believe that I'm going to reinvent the well? :) I use a good encryption algorithm, I guess!